# Android - creating LinearLayout with non-static number of fields (TextView)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I have to create layout with 7 elements where every of this elements will have variable numbers of items. Something like that:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.lessons">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_margin="5dp"
       android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lessons_text_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
       <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lessons_list_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lessons_text_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lessons_list_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lessons_text_3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lessons_list_3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lessons_text_4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lessons_list_4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lessons_text_5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lessons_list_5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lessons_text_6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lessons_list_6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lessons_text_7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lessons_list_7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But I can't put ListView in ScrollView.  When I create LinearLayout with one TextView and try clone it, there is still one element. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is probably to have the Listview contain both:

`void addFooterView(View v)`
Add a fixed view to appear at the bottom of the list.

`void addHeaderView(View v)`
Add a fixed view to appear at the top of the list.

Take a look at the documentation @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

Answer (score 0):

You forget to close the tag *ScrollView* . But problem doesn't solve just by this.
Why do you want to use so many LinearLayouts?

Comment: Because I need 7 objects (TextView + list of elements)